# Detecting an incoming call in my Unity app

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to make my game pause on incoming phone call. I am wondering if any of this functions which I used can do this. I have used them in my source code but none of them worked.

```cs
void OnApplicationPause(bool paused)
{
    if (paused == true)
    {
        if (!isPaused)
        PauseResume(true);
    }
}

void OnApplicationFocus(bool hasFocus)
{
    if (hasFocus == false)
    {
        if (!isPaused)
            PauseResume(true);
    }
}
```

Also i had found Application.runInBackground() but it is mentioned in documentation that "Note: This property is ignored on Android and iOS".

Answer (score 0):

In iOS and Android, `OnApplicationPause(...)` is expected to be called. This user had the same issue: https://forum.unity.com/threads/onapplicationpause-not-being-called-in-ios-build.455426/

His answer was:

> Apparently, it was not working because I had 'Behaviour in Background' set to Custom instead of Suspend...

Comment: The option  'Behaviour in Background' is only in IOS player settings, so I cannot change it for Android