# How do i detect phone call on iPhone in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do i detect if there is phone call popup, or active talk if OnApplicationFocus and OnApplicationPause does not work on incoming call on iPhone X? (and probably newer)

Comment: Looks similar question as [Detecting an incoming call in my Unity app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49371501/detecting-an-incoming-call-in-my-unity-app).

Comment: "Enable Custom Background Behaviors" is not checked in iOS settings.

Comment: It seems like application is not treated like in background, when incoming call is only a small popup on top of the screen?